# How to programmatically add a field to all product types?

Tags: commerce

In Drupal 7, I need to programmatically add a file field to all product types. I've tried the following in the enable hook for my module, but to no avail:

```
$field = array(
  'field_name' => 'my_name',
  'type' => 'file', 
  'cardinality' => -1
);
field_create_field($field);

// Create the instance on the bundle.
$instance = array(
  'field_name' => 'my_name', 
  'entity_type' => 'product', 
  'label' => 'label', 
  'bundle' => 'product', 
  'required' => TRUE,
  'settings' => array(),
  'widget' => array(
    'type' => 'file_generic',
  ),
);
field_create_instance($instance);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure about the entity type?

Answer (score 1):

The entity as defined by drupal commerce should be `commerce_product`:

```
function commerce_product_entity_info() {
  $return = array(
    'commerce_product' => array(
      'label' => t('Commerce Product'),
      ...
    ),
  );
  ...

  return $return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you must get a list of all existing product type, `commerce_product_types()` is the function which will do the job , next for each product type you can add an instance of the created field. final code looks like this :

```
$field = array(
  'field_name' => 'my_name',
  'type' => 'file', 
  'cardinality' => -1
);
field_create_field($field);
$product_types = commerce_product_types();
// Create the instance on the bundle.
foreach ($product_types as $key => $type) {
  $instance = array(
    'field_name' => 'my_name', 
    'entity_type' => 'commerce_product', //commerce_product is true
    'label' => 'label', 
    'bundle' => $key', //Bundle name replaces dynamically
    'required' => TRUE,
    'settings' => array(),
    'widget' => array(
      'type' => 'file_generic',
    ),
  );
  field_create_instance($instance);
}
```